# http GET request without express

Tags: node.js, express

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path="";
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {      
    var buffer = new Buffer(chunk);
    path = buffer.toString();    
    path = path.replace("\n","");
    path = path.replace("\r","");
});
var str="";
var fileRead;
var arrayFiles = [];
function onRequest(request, response) {
    str = "";    
    if (request.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'});
        response.end();
        return;
    } else if (request.url === '/index.html') {
        console.log("Request received" + path);
        fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
        console.log(items);
        arrayFiles = [];
        str += items;
        arrayFiles.push(items);            
        console.log("Enter file to be read"); 
        process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
            var buffer = new Buffer(chunk);
            fileRead = buffer.toString();
            fileRead = fileRead.replace("\n","");
            fileRead = fileRead.replace("\r","");
            if(arrayFiles[0].indexOf(fileRead) != -1) {
                fs.readFile(fileRead, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/plain"});
                    response.write(contents);
                    response.end();
                });
            }
        });
    });
} 
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

The given program displays the files in the directory given as input. And then inputs a file name whose contents are to be displayed.

In the given program, I need the name of the file as input from the user using GET request instead of reading values from stdin. Is it possible to do this without express module. If yes, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "the name of the file", which file? The node.js code file that is executing? Or the file that user uploaded?

Comment: The file whose content is to be displayed @shaochuancs

Comment: I think you can put the filename as URL parameter, such as `GET /index.html?filename=test.txt`

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any questions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve the filename sent from HTTP GET request with plain Node.js http code, without any Express stuff.

The method is: pass filename as URL parameter, and parse it in server side. Here is an example:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let params = req.url.substring(req.url.lastIndexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  let filename = null;
  for (let p of params) {
    let paramKeyValPair = p.split('=');
    if (paramKeyValPair[0] === 'filename') {
      filename = paramKeyValPair[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(filename);
  // deal with filename
  res.end('Hello');
}).listen(8327);
```

For URL like `/index.html?filename=test.txt`, the `filename` variable in server side would be `test.txt`